# What is $\gneq$?

Tags: inequality, notation

I've seen someone asking [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89583/how-do-i-prove-1-frac1nn-n-by-mathematical-induction) with $\gneq$ (`$\gneq$`) in it. What does it mean? What's the difference with $\geq$ (`$\geq$`)?

Comment: "gneq" means "greater than not equal".  For the meaning, we will need to see some context.  If it is in a question, then there is a natural place to get clarification, right?

Comment: But I am waiting to hear for someone, that is the question correctly posed ? , or there is a need for some edit ?

Comment: @GEdgar : But we can simply use "greater than sign" which means that they are not equal implicitly

Comment: @iyengar:The title seems correct to me and the difference is only the second part of the question.

Comment: @MaX : That's what I told

Comment: @iyengar: The question is fine. The OP has asked for the distinction between two symbols. You think they should ask about other symbols; that is your opinion.

Comment: It's been a long time, but I vaguely recall that when talking about partially ordered sets and lattices and the like, one often sees $<$ with the condition $a<a$, so that $<$ will sometimes "really" be $leq$.  This is similar to the existence of notations $\subset$, $\subseteq$, and $\subsetneq$

Comment: @ZevChonoles : Then According to OP question it means that he is asking the difference between $A\gneq B$ and $A\ge B$ , we can surely tell the difference the former one allows $A$ not equal to $B$ but latter one allows $A$ to be equal to $B$, what do you say?

Comment: But I think the question should be "What's the difference between $\gneq$ and $\gt$ ? , as if $A\gneq B$ it implicitly means that $A\gt B$, but what's the need of using the different symbols then, we can directly use $A \gt B$ as it means implicitly that "$A $ is greater than $B$, which implies that they are not equal anymore, so I think that $\gneq$ and $\gt$ mean the same, Don't they ?

Comment: We need the context.  When writing $A \gneq B$, what are $A,B$?  Maybe there is some meaning defined for rather frugal loopoids $A,B$ and $A \gneq B$ and $A \ge B$ have different meanings...  So we must await the return of Oltarus to find the source.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would think $\gneq$ means exactly the same as $>$, i.e. it would mean greater than and **not** equal to (while the symbol $\geq$ means greater than **or** equal to). But of course there may be some specialized use where it doesn't mean this though; everything depends on context.

In the context of [the question you linked to](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89583/how-do-i-prove-1-frac1nn-n-by-mathematical-induction), I can say with certainty that the intended meaning is the one above. That is,

$$n\gneq 3 \iff n>3 \iff n\text{ is greater than }3$$
and, because $n$ is an integer in this context, we can also say that
$$n\gneq 3\iff n\geq 4.$$

As Rasmus points out below, the analogous notations with [set inclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset), $\subset$ vs. $\subsetneq$, unfortunately do **not** mean the same in general; many authors use $A \subset B$ to mean "$A$ is a subset of $B$, and could be equal to $B$". An unambiguous alternative to express that would be to write $\subseteq$.

Comment: What is the specialized context?

Comment: This is clearly the general usage. It might be worthwile to point out that the set-theoretic notation $\subset$ is not universally used for proper inclusion. To be on the safe side, most people only use $\subseteq$ and $\subsetneq$.

Comment: @iyengar: I don't know. That's why I said **may**.

Comment: @Rasmus: Thanks for the suggestion, I've *included* that (ha!)

Comment: @ZevChonoles : you suggested me that question was fine, but you look at it once, the OP asked the difference between $\gneq$ and $\ge$, but your answer was telling the difference between $\gneq$ and $\gt$, thats why I have been saying that question should be edited, and you said its "fine".

Comment: @iyengar: My answer is not telling the difference between $\gneq$ and $>$, it was *explaining the meaning of $\gneq$ by claiming it is interchangeable with $>$*. At any rate I have now included a comment contrasting this with $\geq$.

Comment: @ZevChonoles : But that is not the one OP asked

Comment: @iyengar: If one says "A means the same as B", where B is widely considered to have a different meaning than C, then one has explained the difference between A and C.

Comment: @ZevChonoles : "OP asked that what is the difference between $\gneq$ and $\ge$, but your answer was primarily explaining the similarity between $\gneq$ and $gt$ ( recently you added something in the answer present in brackets ) , but the point I was stressing was that "OP might have thought to ask the difference between the $\gneq$ and $gt$ but used "$\ge$ " instead of "$\gt"$, if the question is re-edited it would make much sense, but the question present in the above form is universally known as everyone knows the difference between $\gneq$ and $ge$. You understood my point ?

Answer (score 3):

$ a \geq b$ means that $a$ is greater than $b$ **or** it can be equal to $b$.

$a \gneq b$ means $a$ is greater than $b$ **and** it can't be equal to $b$.

The $\gneq$ sign used when we want to emphasis that they can't be eqaul.

for example I can write $x^2 +1 \geq 0$ and it is true because it means $x^2 +1$ is greater than zero **or** it can be equal to zero. (I hope you remember how the *or* operator works.)

but it is better to say that $x^2 +1 \gneq 0$ which means $x^2 +1$ is greater than zero **and** it can't be zero.

Comment: "good try" -??? That sounds diminutive. iyengar, there's no difference.

Comment: yes we can write $x^2+1 \gt 0$ but when we write $x^2+1 \gneq 0$ we emphasis that it can't be zero. I mean the point is emphasizing because I've seen this sign when it was necessary to not be equal. For example when the statement is in the denominator of a fraction and we want to emphasis that it can't be zero. And Thanks for the +1!

Comment: @Bardia : Very nice answer !! , convinced with it, why can't you include the same application of fractions in your answer

Comment: @TheChaz : dimunitive ? , I never know the person before, but just wanted to tell so, but if you mind keeping that I better delete it

Comment: @iyengar: fair enough! I should have included that example too.

Comment: @Bardia : do it now ! , nice example, I was waiting for such practical application, really practical situation to contrast their usage, I searched in google for much time, but didn't found any such examples or situations.