# An inequality $\,\, (1+1/n)^n<3-1/n \,$using mathematical induction

Tags: inequality, induction

It was shown in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89583/how-do-i-prove-1-frac1nn-n-by-mathematical-induction?lq=1) that $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n < n$ for $n>3$. I think we can be come up with a better bound, as follows:

> $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \le 3-\frac{1}{n}$$
>   for all natural number $n$.

The result is true for all real number $\ge 1$, which can be shown using calculus. I wonder if the above result can be proved using mathematical induction?

I have tried but fail! Anyway, this question is also inspired by, and related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207675/prove-frac1-n1-frac1-n2-cdots-frac12n-frac2536-by-mathe?rq=1).

**Edit:**

I also found that $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n+k}\right)^n \le 3-\frac{k+1}{n}$$ for all natural number $k$, some large $N$ and $n > N$. This implies that $$\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^n \le 2-\frac{1}{n}.$$

And again, I can't prove any of them using Mathematical Induction.

Comment: In order to use induction, I need to have $\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^n < 3-\frac{2}{n}$ for $n\ge 2$, which again is not trivial. Equivalently, it is to prove $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n -\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^n >\frac{1}{n}$ for $n \ge 2$.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I prove this inequality does not use induction, but I think this proof also elementary proof, because this proof does not use calculus.

$$\begin{array}{lcl}
\left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n &=& 1+\binom{n}{1} \frac{1}{n}+ \sum_{k=2}^n\binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{n^k}\\ &=&2+\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k!} \frac{n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)}{n^k}\\
&\le& 2+\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k!} \le  2+\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k(k-1)} \\ &=& 3-\frac{1}{n}
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Typo, 1st line, right side, $n$ should be $1/n$.

Comment: Nice proof. +1.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks!

Comment: @tetori, thanks for the nice proof. Anyway, I am thinking of mathematical induction...

Comment: So simple and elegant!  +1