# Prove that $\log(n!)=\Theta(n\log n)$ without appealing to Stirling's formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, asymptotics

### Problem

> Prove that $\log(n!)=\Theta(n\log n)$ without appealing to Stirling's formula.

Can somebody please verify my solution to this problem?

### Solution

In this solution, I am going to use the following Lemma without proof:

**Lemma**. If $n$ is a positive integer, then $\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n<3$.

(For a proof, this inequality follows directly from the result proven in [this other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/307786/22335).)

We want to show that $\log(n!)=\Theta(n\log n)$.

First, we will show that $\log(n!)=O(n\log n)$, and then we will show that $n\log n=O(\log(n!))$.

1. Proof of $\log(n!)=O(n\log n)$:

   For $n\geq 1$, $\log(n!)\leq\log(n^n)=n\log n$, as required.
2. Proof of $n\log n=O(\log(n!))$:

   To show this, it's sufficient to prove the following Claim:

   **Claim**: $n\log n \leq 2\log(n!)$ for $n \geq 2$.

   **Proof**: The Claim is equivalent to $\log n^n \leq \log((n!)^2)$, which is true if $n^n \leq (n!)^2$. We will prove this by induction.

   - **Induction hypothesis**: $P(n)::=n^n \leq (n!)^2$.
   - **Base case** ($n=2$): $P(2)$ is true, because $2^2=4\leq (2!)^2=4$.
   - **Inductive step**: Assume $P(n)$ is true for some $n\geq 2$. We want to show that $P(n+1)$ is true:

     $$(n+1)^{n+1} \leq [(n+1)!]^2$$

     By the induction hypothesis, we have:

     $$n^n \leq (n!)^2$$

     Multiplying both sides by $\dfrac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^n}$, we get:

     $$(n+1)^{n+1} \leq \dfrac{(n!)^2(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^n}$$

     To prove $P(n+1)$, we want to show that

     $$\dfrac{(n!)^2(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^n}\leq [(n+1)!]^2$$

     But $[(n+1)!]^2=(n+1)^2(n!)^2$, so the above inequality is equivalent to:

     $$\dfrac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^n}\leq (n+1)^2$$

     This inequality becomes:

     $$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n\leq n+1$$

     By the Lemma stated in the beginning of this solution, the expression $(1+1/n)^n$ has an upper bound of $3$ for all positive integers $n$. And, since $n \geq 2$, we have $n+1 \geq 3$. So, the above inequality is true, because:

     $$\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n\leq 3\leq n+1$$

     This proves $P(n+1)$.

   We have proven the Claim, which implies that $n\log n=O(\log(n!))$.

### EDIT

---

Based on the hint in Milten's answer, here is an attempt at a shorter proof for $n\log n=O(\log(n!))$:

$$\begin{aligned}
\log n!&= \sum_{m=1}^n \log m\ge \sum_{m=\lceil n/2\rceil}^n \log m\\
&\ge (n/2)\log(n/2)\\
&= (n/2)\log n - (n/2)\log 2\\
&\ge (n/2)\log n - (n/2)\log 2\cdot\frac{\log n}{2\log 2}&\text{ (for }n\ge 4\text{)}\\
&= (n/2)\log n - (n/4)\log n\\
&= \dfrac{1}{4}n\log n\\
\end{aligned}$$

So, $n\log n\leq 4\log n!$ for $n\geq 4$. This shows that $n\log n=O(\log n!)$.

Comment: $$(n/2)^{n/2}\le n! \le n^n$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks correct :) But I will mention that there is a more straightforward way to show the $\Omega$ part, which starts with
$$
\log n! 
= \sum_{m=1}^n \log m
\ge \sum_{m=n/2}^n \log m
$$

Comment: $\ge$  does not lead you to $\Theta$, does it ?

Comment: $\ge$ leads to $\Omega$, and OP already proved $O$ nice and easy.

Comment: Agreed but it is not clear which part of the question you are addressing.

Comment: Thanks, edited.

Comment: @Milten I included an alternative solution attempt for the $\Omega$ part in the original question, based on your hint. Can you please check?

Comment: @favq It looks good. To be pedantic, $n/2$ is not an integer for odd $n$, so we should deal with that somehow or other (since we can’t sum from $n/2$ then). But it doesn’t change the idea at all.

Comment: @Milten Good point. Choosing $m=\lceil n/2\rceil$ as the lower bound of the sum seems to resolve this issue: $\sum_{m=\lceil n/2\rceil}^n \log m$. In this case, if $n$ is either odd or even, the number of elements in the sum ($n-\lceil n/2\rceil+1$) will be $\geq n/2$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$$\sum\log i\sim\int\log t\, dt$$

You can add details to obtain a precise bracketing, but this is the "heart" of the answer.

Comment: Together with $\sum log(x_i)=log(\prod(x_i))$, I guess

Answer (score 1):

$n^n<(n!)^2$ is equivalent to $n^{n/2}<n!$, or $(\sqrt n)^n<n!$, or the cleverly in-between:
$$(n^{\frac23})^{\frac 34n}<n!.$$
Now observe that for $n>4^3$, the top $\frac34n$ factors in the definition of $n!$ are $\ge\frac 14n>n^{\frac23}$.