# Let $a_n = n^{1/n}$ and $b_n = {a_{n+1}}/{a_n}$, prove that $\{b_n\}_{n=5}^{\infty}$ is increasing.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n = n^{1/n}$ and $b_n = \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$. I am trying to prove that $\{b_n\}_{n=5}^{\infty}$ is increasing. Here is what I know and what I've tried:

- The first few elements of $b_n$ aren't increasing (because $a_n$ is decreasing only after $n \geq 3$, for instance.) and so it wouldn't be correct to prove that $b_n$ is increasing for all $n$. Then letting $S(n)$ be the statement $$b_{n} = \frac{(n+1)^{1/(n+1)}}{n^{1/n}} \leq \frac{(n+2)^{1/(n+2)}}{(n+1)^{1/(n+1)}} = b_{n+1}$$ we can assume $S(n-1)$ and prove $S(n)$ (and $S(5)$). I tried to do this by breaking apart the exponents and manipulating the inequalities but I couldn't get anywhere.
- The other thing I tried was to prove that $$a_n^{2} \leq a_{n-1}a_{n+1}$$ using a convexity argument, particularly if $f(n) = n^{1/n}$ that $$a_n = f(n) = f(\frac{(n-1) + (n+1)}{2}) \leq \frac{f(n-1) + f(n+1)}{2} = \frac{a_{n-1} + a_{n+1}}{2}$$ I figured the AM-GM inequality might be useful because of the RHS but it implies that $$a_{n-1}a_{n+1} \leq (\frac{a_{n-1} + a_{n+1}}{2})^2$$ which doesn't seem to help bound $a_n^2$ above.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991212/let-a-n-sqrtnn-and-b-n-a-n1-a-n-prove-that-b-n-n-5-inft) is identical to mine but I'm looking for an approach that doesn't make use of logarithms or differentiation, since the book I'm working through hasn't covered those yet.

If I could have a small hint to point me in the right direction I would appreciate it!

Comment: I am using Foundations of Mathematical Analysis, by Pfaffenberger. The question is 16.12, and the logarithm is defined in section 67.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof: $\sqrt[n]{n} &gt; \sqrt[n+1]{n+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1495289/proof-sqrtnn-sqrtn1n1)

Comment: And another one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77935/prove-by-induction-that-for-all-n-geq-3-nn1-n1n/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is no hard to prove $(1+\dfrac1n)^n$ is increasing and $(1+\dfrac1n)^n<e$, then
$$\left(\dfrac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}\right)^{n(n+1)(n+2)}=\left(\dfrac{a_{n+2}a_{n}}{a_{n+1}^2}\right)^{n(n+1)(n+2)}=\dfrac{(n+2)^{n(n+1)}n^{(n+1)(n+2)}}{(n+1)^{2n(n+2)}}=$$
$$\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{n+2}{n+1}\right)^{n(n+1)}}{\left(\dfrac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n(n+3)}}n^2 = \left(\dfrac{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}}{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n}}\right)^n\dfrac{n}{\left((1+\dfrac1n)^n\right)^\frac32}>\dfrac{n}{e^\frac32}>1$$
valid if $n>e^\frac32>4$.

Comment: Interesting that you came up with the same bound ($n > e^{3/2}$) that I did. I think that your answer is much better, also.

Comment: @martycohen thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$a_n = n^{1/n}
$
and
$b_n = \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
$.

Let
$c_n
=\ln(a_n)
=\dfrac{ln(n)}{n}
$
and

$\begin{array}\\
d_n
&=\ln(b_n)\\
&=\ln(a_{n+1})-\ln(a_n)\\
&=\dfrac{ln(n+1)}{n+1}-\dfrac{ln(n)}{n}\\
&=\dfrac{nln(n+1)-(n+1)\ln(n)}{n(n+1)}\\
&=\dfrac{n(\ln(n)+ln(1+1/n))-n\ln(n)-\ln(n)}{n(n+1)}\\
&=\dfrac{n\ln(n)+nln(1+1/n)-n\ln(n)-\ln(n)}{n(n+1)}\\
&=\dfrac{nln(1+1/n)-\ln(n)}{n(n+1)}\\
&=\dfrac{ln(1+1/n)}{n+1}-\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n(n+1)}\\
\text{so}\\
d_n'
&= \dfrac{(2 n + 1) (\ln(n) - 1) - n^2 \ln(1/n + 1)}{n^2 (n + 1)^2}\\
\end{array}
$

If we can show that

$e_n
=(2 n + 1) (\ln(n) - 1)  - n^2 \ln(1/n + 1)
\gt 0$
for large enough $n$
(Wolfy says $n > 4.05$),
we are done.

$n^2 \ln(1/n + 1)
\lt n^2\dfrac1{n}
=n$
so

$\begin{array}\\
e_n
&=(2 n + 1) (\ln(n) - 1)  - n^2 \ln(1/n + 1)\\
&\gt (2 n + 1) (\ln(n) - 1)-n\\
&= (2 n + 1) \ln(n) - (2n+1)-n\\
&= (2 n + 1) \ln(n) - (3n+1)\\
&= (2 n + 1) \left(\ln(n) - \dfrac{3n+1}{2n+1}\right)\\
&= (2 n + 1) \left(\ln(n) - \left(\dfrac{3n+1}{2n+1}-\dfrac32+\dfrac32\right)\right)\\
&= (2 n + 1) \left(\ln(n) - \left(\dfrac{(3n+1)2-(2n+1)3}{2(2n+1)}+\dfrac32\right)\right)\\
&= (2 n + 1) \left(\ln(n)-\dfrac32+ \dfrac{1}{2(2n+1)}\right)\\
&= (2 n + 1) \left(\ln(n)-\dfrac32\right)+\dfrac12\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if
$\ln(n) \gt \dfrac32$,
or
$n > e^{3/2}
\approx 4.481$.
this is true.

Therefore
this is true for
$n \ge 5$.

Comment: From the question: *".. but I'm looking for an approach that doesn't make use of logarithms or differentiation, since the book I'm working through hasn't covered those yet."*