# Find the maximum among $1, \sqrt {2}, \sqrt[3]{3}... $

Tags: inequality

Find the maximum among the following :-

$1, \sqrt {2}, \sqrt[3]{3}... $

I think the answer is $\sqrt[3]{3}$.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Even older http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77935/prove-by-induction-that-for-all-n-geq-3-nn1-n1n/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By raising both sides to the $n(n+1)$-th power, it is enough to prove that 
$$ n^{n+1} > (n+1)^n $$
or, by dividing both sides by $n^n$,
$$ n > \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n $$
that follows from
$$ n > \color{red}{e} > \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n.$$

Comment: @Macavity: this answer was migrated from a duplicate question, only dealing with the $n>2$ case. In the actual case we obviously have to deal with $n=1$ and $n=2$ by hand.